# how to make expression as below? rdlc expression

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, rdlc

im using vb.net 2010.  sqlserver 2008 R2
database Table

- task

attributes / column

- task
- percentage

each task have percentage like :

> 1st task - 10%
>
> 2nd task - 30%
>
> 3rd task - 70%

i want to calculate total percentage

> formula = (sum(total percentage) / (count(total percentage) * 100)) *
>   100%
>
> example = (sum(1st, 2nd, 3rd ) / (count(1st, 2nd , 3rd) *100 ) ) *100%
>
> calculation process = (110% / 300%) * 100%
>
> results  = 36.6666 %

so. how to implement this calculation in rdlc expression? im not familiar with the rdlc
like something below? any leads would be awesome! :)

> =Fields!percentage.Value

Comment: Is that you have fields below : Fields!percentage.Value, Fields!Task1.Value, Fields!Task2.Value, Fields!Task3.Value  Or do you have a single field Fields!Task.Value

Comment: no. its Fields!percentage.Value only. task1,task2,task3 is the value inside percentage column. hm poor english. sorry

Comment: So, Here is the summary of your ques. You have a column named Percent. You want to apply the percent value in formula((sum(total percentage) / (count(total percentage) * 100)) * 100%). And Count of Percent is the total number of values in the Percent column.

Comment: Try my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below formula for the field `Fields!percentage.Value`:

```
=(Sum(Fields!percentage.Value) / (count(Fields!percentage.Value) * 100)) * 100
```

Or Try this:**(Avg = Total / No of items)** (Not your formula)

```
=(Sum(Fields!percentage.Value) / (Count(Fields!percentage.Value)))
```

And update what you got.

Comment: hey. thankyou ive solved the problem. 
but heres my code

>=(Sum(Fields!percentage.Value) / (Count(Fields!percentage.Value)))

could you tell the difference? its has the same result. mind clarify.  @Veera . thankyou

Comment: Hey, it is simple maths. we multiply count with 100 and divide the result from sum. which is 100 times of sum/count. And again we multiply 100 to that. as we know 100/100 = 1. so, sum/count is equal to (sum/ count * 100) * 100. Anyway, You only asked the result for the formula. Both are same. I updated the ans with your code also.